# How to Concatenate an Asp.net control name with a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I have a few asp.net objects.  I get the ID of object 1 and assign it to a string.  I then want to add a control to a placeholder than end in that ID.  Not too sure how to go about doing this.

```
        string id = Regex.Match(btnCreateHazard.ID, @"\d+$").Value;
        phHazard(SOMEHOW GET THE ID HERE).Controls.Add(txtHazardDesc);
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What i understood id  you want to add a string to a control that u can do like this..

```
 string id = Regex.Match(btnCreateHazard.ID, @"\d+$").Value;
 placeholderId.Controls.Add(id);
```

OR

can refer below example.
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx